# What is a safe way to compact/optimize a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, optimization, compact-database

I wanted to `compact` some collections, and to my surprise this is not as straightforward as I thought. It failed after a couple of seconds and now I cannot connect to the database anymore:

```
Collection: MyDB.logs
---
Indexes         : 7
Extents         : 9
Documents       : 59278

Size            : 8824KB
Storage size    : 12376KB
Index size      : 2888KB
Compacting MyDB.logs...
Fri Sep 26 13:14:40.919 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Fri Sep 26 13:14:41.086 Error: error doing query: failed at src/mongo/shell/query.js:78
```

As you can see in the log below, this happened because there is not enough memory:
`Assertion: 13524:out of memory`

This also breaks the MongoDB daemon:

```
$ mongo MyDB
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: MyDB
Fri Sep 26 13:38:00.730 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

This is a terrible idea. Shutting down the daemon makes downtime longer. One would think server side operations like this are clever enough to see if a certain operation can make it, and gracefully cancel the operation or roll back the problem, without shutting down the daemon until reboot.

**What is a safe way to compact/optimize a collection?**

---

Although this is about the `compact` statement, here is the full script I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env mongo

// Stats and fixes
// Redsandro 2014-09-26

var dbName = 'MyDB';
print('Connecting to: '+ dbName);
print('---');

myDb=db.getSiblingDB(dbName);

print();

myDb.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (collectionName) {
    // print('Collection: ' + collectionName);

    var stats = myDb[collectionName].stats(10240);
    print('Collection: ' + stats.ns);
    print('---');

    print('Indexes         : ' + stats.nindexes);
    print('Extents         : ' + stats.numExtents);
    print('Documents       : ' + stats.count);
    print();
    print('Size            : ' + stats.size + 'KB');
    print('Storage size    : ' + stats.storageSize + 'KB');
    print('Index size      : ' + stats.totalIndexSize + 'KB');

    print('Compacting ' + stats.ns + '...');
    myDb.runCommand({ compact: collectionName }); // BREAKS!!!!111

    print('Done.');
    print();
});
```

---

Here is `mongodb.log`:

```
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.696 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:44775 #26 (6 connections now open)
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.714 [conn26] compact MyDB.logs begin
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.714 [conn26] paddingFactor:1 paddingBytes:0
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.714 [conn26] compact 9 extents
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.715 [conn26] compact orphan deleted lists
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.715 [conn26] compact dropping indexes
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.732 [conn26] compact begin extent #0 for namespace MyDB.logs
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.732 [conn26] compact paging in len=0.028672MB
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.732 [conn26] compact copying records
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.750 [conn26] compact finished extent #0 containing 35 documents (0.027904MB) oldPadding: 1.03077 1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.750 [conn26] compact begin extent #1 for namespace MyDB.logs
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.750 [conn26] compact paging in len=0.192512MB
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.750 [conn26] compact copying records
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.760 [conn26] compact finished extent #1 containing 341 documents (0.187024MB) oldPadding: 1.03333 1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.760 [conn26] compact begin extent #2 for namespace MyDB.logs
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.760 [conn26] compact paging in len=0.770048MB
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.760 [conn26] compact copying records
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.782 [conn26] compact finished extent #2 containing 616 documents (0.76MB) oldPadding: 1.053 1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.782 [conn26] compact begin extent #3 for namespace MyDB.logs
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.782 [conn26] compact paging in len=3.08019MB
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.785 [conn26] compact copying records
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.924 [conn26] compact finished extent #3 containing 2062 documents (3.04699MB) oldPadding: 1.05165 1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.924 [conn26] compact begin extent #4 for namespace MyDB.logs
Fri Sep 26 13:14:30.924 [conn26] compact paging in len=12.3208MB
Fri Sep 26 13:14:31.280 [conn26] compact copying records
Fri Sep 26 13:14:31.694 [conn26] compact finished extent #4 containing 8447 documents (12.1854MB) oldPadding: 1.04567 1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:31.694 [conn26] compact begin extent #5 for namespace MyDB.logs
Fri Sep 26 13:14:31.694 [conn26] compact paging in len=16.6339MB
Fri Sep 26 13:14:32.458 [conn26] compact copying records
Fri Sep 26 13:14:33.120 [conn26] compact finished extent #5 containing 11406 documents (16.4509MB) oldPadding: 1.0412 1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:33.120 [conn26] compact begin extent #6 for namespace MyDB.logs
Fri Sep 26 13:14:33.120 [conn26] compact paging in len=22.4584MB
Fri Sep 26 13:14:33.874 [conn26] compact copying records
Fri Sep 26 13:14:34.637 [conn26] compact finished extent #6 containing 19310 documents (22.1493MB) oldPadding: 1.04563 1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:34.637 [conn26] compact begin extent #7 for namespace MyDB.logs
Fri Sep 26 13:14:34.637 [conn26] compact paging in len=30.3186MB
Fri Sep 26 13:14:36.526 [conn26] compact end paging in 1888ms 0.0160586MB/sec
Fri Sep 26 13:14:36.526 [conn26] compact copying records
Fri Sep 26 13:14:39.306 [conn26] compact finished extent #7 containing 15090 documents (30.0768MB) oldPadding: 1.04621 1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:39.306 [conn26] compact begin extent #8 for namespace MyDB.logs
Fri Sep 26 13:14:39.306 [conn26] compact paging in len=40.9313MB
Fri Sep 26 13:14:39.333 [conn26] compact copying records
Fri Sep 26 13:14:40.148 [conn26] compact finished extent #8 containing 1971 documents (5.47893MB) oldPadding: 1.04616 1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:40.148 [conn26] compact create index { _id: 1 }
Fri Sep 26 13:14:40.149 [conn26] build index MyDB.logs { _id: 1 }
Fri Sep 26 13:14:40.564 [conn26] Assertion: 13524:out of memory AlignedBuilder
0xac9f86 0xa8e47a 0xa8d1f8 0xa8d25b 0x8291ed 0x8294c4 0x820011 0x8203ea 0x820d7c 0x792146 0x792e0e 0x88ee1f 0x88c0b0 0x88c6c5 0x903429 0x9053e3 0x88ab23 0x8838a5 0x904cfc 0x6eae7d 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x26) [0xac9f86]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x9a) [0xa8e47a]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xa8d1f8]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14AlignedBuilder8_reallocEjj+0x1b) [0xa8d25b]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x8291ed]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur13PREPLOGBUFFERERNS0_11JSectHeaderERNS_14AlignedBuilderE+0x1c4) [0x8294c4]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x820011]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11DurableImpl9commitNowEv+0x1a) [0x8203ea]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11DurableImpl16_aCommitIsNeededEv+0xac) [0x820d7c]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12BtreeBuilderINS_12BtreeData_V1EE24mayCommitProgressDurablyEv+0x16) [0x792146]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12BtreeBuilderINS_12BtreeData_V1EE6addKeyERNS_7BSONObjENS_7DiskLocE+0x23e) [0x792e0e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo24buildBottomUpPhases2And3INS_12BtreeData_V1EEEvbRNS_12IndexDetailsERNS_21BSONObjExternalSorterEbRSt3setINS_7DiskLocESt4lessIS7_ESaIS7_EEPNS_5CurOpEPNS_12SortPhaseOneERNS_19ProgressMeterHolderERNS_5TimerEb+0x20f) [0x88ee1f]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14fastBuildIndexEPKcPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERNS_12IndexDetailsEb+0x3f0) [0x88c0b0]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12buildAnIndexERKSsPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERNS_12IndexDetailsEbb+0x135) [0x88c6c5]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16insert_makeIndexEPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERKSsRKNS_7DiskLocEb+0x2c9) [0x903429]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr6insertEPKcPKvibbbPb+0x8d3) [0x9053e3]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo17ensureHaveIdIndexEPKcb+0x463) [0x88ab23]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo19prepareToBuildIndexERKNS_7BSONObjEbbRSsRPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERS0_+0x1155) [0x8838a5]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr6insertEPKcPKvibbbPb+0x1ec) [0x904cfc]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8_compactEPKcPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERSsbRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEdi+0x119d) [0x6eae7d]
Fri Sep 26 13:14:40.696 [conn26] dbexception in groupCommit causing immediate shutdown: 13524 out of memory AlignedBuilder
Fri Sep 26 13:14:40.696 gc1
Fri Sep 26 13:14:40.774 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

Fri Sep 26 13:14:40.789 Backtrace:
0xac9f86 0x6cfcd4 0x7feff2f5dff0 0x7feff2f5df77 0x7feff2f615e8 0x8944ef 0x820334 0x8203ea 0x820d7c 0x792146 0x792e0e 0x88ee1f 0x88c0b0 0x88c6c5 0x903429 0x9053e3 0x88ab23 0x8838a5 0x904cfc 0x6eae7d 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x26) [0xac9f86]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x254) [0x6cfcd4]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36ff0) [0x7feff2f5dff0]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7feff2f5df77]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7feff2f615e8]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10mongoAbortEPKc+0x4f) [0x8944ef]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x820334]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11DurableImpl9commitNowEv+0x1a) [0x8203ea]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11DurableImpl16_aCommitIsNeededEv+0xac) [0x820d7c]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12BtreeBuilderINS_12BtreeData_V1EE24mayCommitProgressDurablyEv+0x16) [0x792146]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12BtreeBuilderINS_12BtreeData_V1EE6addKeyERNS_7BSONObjENS_7DiskLocE+0x23e) [0x792e0e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo24buildBottomUpPhases2And3INS_12BtreeData_V1EEEvbRNS_12IndexDetailsERNS_21BSONObjExternalSorterEbRSt3setINS_7DiskLocESt4lessIS7_ESaIS7_EEPNS_5CurOpEPNS_12SortPhaseOneERNS_19ProgressMeterHolderERNS_5TimerEb+0x20f) [0x88ee1f]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14fastBuildIndexEPKcPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERNS_12IndexDetailsEb+0x3f0) [0x88c0b0]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12buildAnIndexERKSsPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERNS_12IndexDetailsEbb+0x135) [0x88c6c5]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16insert_makeIndexEPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERKSsRKNS_7DiskLocEb+0x2c9) [0x903429]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr6insertEPKcPKvibbbPb+0x8d3) [0x9053e3]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo17ensureHaveIdIndexEPKcb+0x463) [0x88ab23]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo19prepareToBuildIndexERKNS_7BSONObjEbbRSsRPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERS0_+0x1155) [0x8838a5]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr6insertEPKcPKvibbbPb+0x1ec) [0x904cfc]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8_compactEPKcPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERSsbRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEdi+0x119d) [0x6eae7d]
```

Comment: What does the mongod log file say when the compact command was run? What error does the server throw on startup?

Comment: The error is: _Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed_

I added the log do the question.

Comment: mongod crashed. You need to bring it back up before you can reconnect. The compact ran out of memory, which caused the crash. How much RAM do you have available? What are the sizes of your indexes?

Comment: About 45MB total. There was a factor 10 bug in my stats script. This particular instance had about 512MB of RAM. Running minimal Ubuntu (and having a lot of SWAP) I cannot imagine this would cause breakage.

Comment: Have a look at the line "dbException in groupCommit causing immediate shutdown.", which leaves little space for imagination. ;) Clearly wdberkeley is right. And I am pretty sure that compaction isn't a performance booster, since MongoDB works with memory mapped files. The only real useful thing I see in compact is that it allows to change the padding factor, which you didn't do. Yeah, there are cases in which the allocation of an additional data file might be prevented through compaction, but given today's GB prices, that's not even worth the time starting a compaction.